# Shipping rate calculation in Table rate Shipping method Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, table-rates

I am developing custom shipping method similar to Table rate Shipping method in which I am comparing Product SKU instead of Product Weight/Price.

I am able to import CSV with this change and store CSV data in my custom table successfully.

Now i am not able to find code in Table rate shipping method which is responsible for comparing Product weight/Price with CSV Weight/Price and display shipping rate accordingly in Checkout page.

If anybody has studied Table rate shipping method code, Please guide to find code block for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open **vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php**

```
/**
 * Get rate.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function getRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
{
    return $this->_tablerateFactory->create()->getRate($request);
}
```

> vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Carrier/Tablerate.php

```
/**
 * Return table rate array or false by rate request
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
 * @return array|bool
 */
public function getRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();

    $select = $connection->select()->from($this->getMainTable());
    /** @var RateQuery $rateQuery */
    $rateQuery = $this->rateQueryFactory->create(['request' => $request]);

    $rateQuery->prepareSelect($select);
    $bindings = $rateQuery->getBindings();

    $result = $connection->fetchRow($select, $bindings);
    // Normalize destination zip code
    if ($result && $result['dest_zip'] == '*') {
        $result['dest_zip'] = '';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Also check

> vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/ResourceModel/Carrier/Tablerate/RateQuery.php

```
public function prepareSelect(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select)
```

Now calculation shipping price:

> vendor/magento/module-shipping/Model/Carrier/AbstractCarrier.php

```
/**
 * Get the handling fee for the shipping + cost
 *
 * @param float $cost
 * @return float final price for shipping method
 */
public function getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($cost)
{
    $handlingFee = (float)$this->getConfigData('handling_fee');
    $handlingType = $this->getConfigData('handling_type');
    if (!$handlingType) {
        $handlingType = self::HANDLING_TYPE_FIXED;
    }
    $handlingAction = $this->getConfigData('handling_action');
    if (!$handlingAction) {
        $handlingAction = self::HANDLING_ACTION_PERORDER;
    }

    return $handlingAction == self::HANDLING_ACTION_PERPACKAGE ? $this->_getPerpackagePrice(
        $cost,
        $handlingType,
        $handlingFee
    ) : $this->_getPerorderPrice(
        $cost,
        $handlingType,
        $handlingFee
    );
}
```